# Unable to import large cache of .xlsx files - Receive error BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, import, encoding

I am looking to import a cache of .xlsx files from a local folder. This type of one stop shop import has worked before with newer Excel workbooks, but this current cache consists of large workbooks (+4MB) from 2020.

When I use the following code, I receive the following error:
BadZipFile: File is not a zip file.

However, none of the files are zip files. Could this be an encoding issue?

```
path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)
files

files_xls2 = [f for f in files if f[-14:] == '2020_File.xlsx']
files_xls2
sheet_name2 = '6 Commodities-A'

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for f in files_xls2:
    data2 = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name2, engine='openpyxl')
```

Comment: This above code does work for newer Excel workbooks (produced in 2021), but not for older ones. In terms of external connections, would it then be an issue of removing them workbook by workbook before an import can happen?

Answer (score 0):

`xlsx` files [are indeed zipped XML files](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML). Your error suggests that your file might be corrupted, or not a valid xlsx file.

Comment: Thanks. They are all .xlsx files, but as far as their being corrupted goes, I am not sure. They all seem to open without an issue. There are many connections within them, though, such as to PowerBI. Not sure if that could mess with them.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas does not work with external connections, which could be why your files are getting corrupted, as you mention yourself.